# convert only the first column in a file to lower case

Tags: awk, string, case-sensitivity

I have a file on RedHat with the data below:

```
$ cat hello.txt
mumdfw2as123v USER=wladmin                                                MOUNTPOINT=/apps
MUMFW2as97v.mrshmc.com USER=wladmin                                      MOUNTPOINT=/apps
MUMFW3AS65V USER=user                                                    MOUNTPOINT=DR-/u
MUMDFW3AS66V USER=oracle                                                  MOUNTPOINT=/u
mumdfw3AS69v_oracle ansible_host=mumdfw3as69v USER=oracle                 MOUNTPOINT=/web
```

I wish to convert only the first column to lowercase and save the changes to the same file.

I do not have `nawk` tool as I did find a solution using 'nawk'

Can you please suggest?

Comment: You don't need `nawk`, just use `awk`. Also, what operating system are you using?

Comment: @terdon redhat linux

Comment: If you found a solution using `nawk` then you have a solution using any `awk` as `nawk`, despite it's terrible name, is a very old, pre-POSIX version of `awk` and all other `awk`s have a superset of `nawk`s functionality (e.g. POSIX character classes).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a simple approach:

```
$ awk -F'[ ]' '{$1=tolower($1)}1' file
mumdfw2as123v USER=wladmin                                                MOUNTPOINT=/apps
mumfw2as97v.mrshmc.com USER=wladmin                                      MOUNTPOINT=/apps
mumfw3as65v USER=user                                                    MOUNTPOINT=DR-/u
mumdfw3as66v USER=oracle                                                  MOUNTPOINT=/u
mumdfw3as69v_oracle ansible_host=mumdfw3as69v USER=oracle                 MOUNTPOINT=/web
```

That simply changes `$1` (the first field) to itself in lower case. The `1` at the end is `awk` shorthand for "print this line". The fun bit is the `-F'[ ]'` where we are setting the input field separator to a space, but because it is presented as a regular expression (a character class), that forces awk to recalculate the input line and means we can keep the original spacing of the input file. Without it, we would get:

```
$ awk '{$1=tolower($1)}1' file
mumdfw2as123v USER=wladmin MOUNTPOINT=/apps
mumfw2as97v.mrshmc.com USER=wladmin MOUNTPOINT=/apps
mumfw3as65v USER=user MOUNTPOINT=DR-/u
mumdfw3as66v USER=oracle MOUNTPOINT=/u
mumdfw3as69v_oracle ansible_host=mumdfw3as69v USER=oracle MOUNTPOINT=/web
```

To edit the file in place, you can use GNU `awk` (the default on linux systems):

```
$ gawk -F'[ ]' -i inplace '{$1=tolower($1)}1' file
$ cat file
mumdfw2as123v USER=wladmin                                                MOUNTPOINT=/apps
mumfw2as97v.mrshmc.com USER=wladmin                                      MOUNTPOINT=/apps
mumfw3as65v USER=user                                                    MOUNTPOINT=DR-/u
mumdfw3as66v USER=oracle                                                  MOUNTPOINT=/u
mumdfw3as69v_oracle ansible_host=mumdfw3as69v USER=oracle                 MOUNTPOINT=/web
```

Answer (score 2):

[@terdon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/659006/133219) is better but here's an alternative approach just as an FYI:

```
$ awk '{match($0,/[^[:space:]]+/); print tolower(substr($0,1,RLENGTH)) substr($0,RLENGTH+1)}' hello.txt
mumdfw2as123v USER=wladmin                                                MOUNTPOINT=/apps
mumfw2as97v.mrshmc.com USER=wladmin                                      MOUNTPOINT=/apps
mumfw3as65v USER=user                                                    MOUNTPOINT=DR-/u
mumdfw3as66v USER=oracle                                                  MOUNTPOINT=/u
mumdfw3as69v_oracle ansible_host=mumdfw3as69v USER=oracle                 MOUNTPOINT=/web
```

Answer (score 2):

With perl or GNU sed:

```
perl -pe 's/^\S+/\L$&/' file
```

```
sed -E 's/^\S+/\L&/' file
```

+ `-i` option if you want that

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in the file file.txt

```
awk '{printf "%s", tolower($1);  for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf " %s", $i; print ""}' file.txt
```

Steps Explained

1. Convert first column to lowercase and print it

   `printf "%s", tolower($1)`
2. Print the rest of the columns
   `for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) printf " %s", $i`
3. Print the newline

   `print ""`

Comment: This will remove the original input file's spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Using the utility `perl` we split the record on a position where to its left is nonwhitespace and to the right is a space. In effect we are marking the ending position of a field:

```
perl -F'(?<=\S)(?=\s)' -lane '
  print lc(shift(@F)), @F;
' file.csv
```

---

In Python we do it in a different manner wherein we get the first nonwhitespace run of characters (IOW, the first field) and turn it into lower case by means of the re.sub() method.

```
python3 -c 'import re, sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  for l in f:
    print(re.sub(r"\S+",lambda x:x.group(0).lower(),l,1),end="")
' file.csv
```